# Degree symbol and \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, matlab-prettifier, degrees

How can I print a degree symbol (°) in a listing with `\lstinputlisting`?

I have noticed the questions based on the `lstlisting` environment but it does not work with `\lstinputlisting`.

This illustrate the solution working with the `lstlisting` environment not with `\lstinputlisting`:
[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} % To highligth MATLAB code

\lstset{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    literate={{°}{\textdegree}1}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
{Street name, n° 40}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstinputlisting{test_matlab.m}
    
\end{document}
```

**MATLAB file to print with `\lstinputlisting`**

```
function [others] = Create_structure_others()

    others.a = struct('value', [], 'unit', '°');

end
```

Comment: It works for me without problem. Does the log show some warnings/errors?

Comment: Yes: Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "B0. others.a = struct('value', [], 'unit', '�'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the `.m` file is UTF-8 encoded and convert it if not.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
function [others] = Create_structure_others()

    others.a = struct('value', [], 'unit', '°');

end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} % To highligth MATLAB code

\lstset{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    literate={{°}{\textdegree}1}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
{Street name, n° 40}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure if one can coerce MATLAB into outputting UTF-8, but it should be possible.

I tried to convert the `.m` file into Latin-1 and, indeed, the output is like yours (with error message).

Comment: It does work but MATLAB cannot encode in UTF-8. If someone else needs a solution: I opened the .m file with Notepad++, changed the encoding, replaced the symbols that were lost to the encoding change and saved the file. The LaTeX code now works. Thanks!

Comment: @JuCa Complain with MATLAB: UTF-8 has been a standard for many years.